# If $f(a)=a,f'(a)=1,f''(a)>0$ then $\exists \delta >0:(a,a+\delta)\subset W^c$

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ increasing function.  If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a fixed point of $f$ (so that $f(a) = a$) and $f'(a)=1, f''(a)>0$, show that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $(a,a+\delta)\subset W^c$, where $W = \left\{x : \lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x) = a\right\}.$
>
> Note $f^n(x) := \underbrace{f\circ f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f}_{ \text{$n$ times }}(x)$

I tried to show that if $a<x^*<a+\delta$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f^n(x^*)\neq a$ but I don't really know how to continue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don´t understand. If $f$ is a increasing function, and $x > a$ then $f(x) > f(a) = a \implies f^{n}(x) > f^{n}(a) = a$ for all $n$

Comment: @ZAF an edit has been made.

Comment: I've edited your post for readability (please don't write the entire post using \text inside math mode!) and also for some minor math errors.  Please check the definition I've written for $W$ to make sure it's what you meant (it seems to be from the last part of your post, but you can double-check)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you very much for the edit, i will keep your suggestions in mind. The definition of the set W is right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f''$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f''(x)>f''(a)/2>0$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. This implies $f'$ is increasing on the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$; this is a standard exercise using the mean value theorem. Now fix $x\in(a,a+\delta)$. Applying the mean value theorem again, there exists $x^*\in(a,x)$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(x^*)>f'(a) = 1.$$
Since $f(a)=a$, one can rearrange the above inequality to deduce $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in(a,a+\delta)$.

To finish off the proof, assume for a contradiction that there exists $x\in(a,a+\delta)$ for which $f^n(x)\to a$ as $n\to\infty$. Then there exists $N$ such that $f^n(x)\in(a,a+\delta)$ for all $n\ge N$ (here we also use the fact that $f$ is increasing and $f'(a)>0$). But from our above work, this means $f^{n+1}(x)=f(f^n(x))>f^n(x)$, so this sequence is increasing, contradicting our assumption that its limit is $a$. This completes the proof.